# Sublime Text 3 - auto close hash tag

Tags: coldfusion, matching, hashtag

I have been using ST2 for long time now, for my CFML coding. I have switched to ST3 recently which includes a lot of bug fixes and it's, generally, much better and a descent update.

However, an issue I have, I would like to customize it (somehow) upon typing a single hashtag , I want this to be automatically closed , i.e. the same behavior as happens with brackets, square brackets, single and double quotes, etc.

This used to work on ST2 , but not on ST3.

I have installed the CFML package but still this functionality is not available, at least by default.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Without specifics, I can only recommend re-downloading the package. This works for me: https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion

Comment: @TRose that package is deprecated. The author recommends https://github.com/jcberquist/sublimetext-cfml, which is what I've been using with ST3 w/o problem.

Comment: Fair enough. HEY GIORGOC, LISTEN TO THIS GUY.

Comment: @TRose , uninstalling/reinstalling the package didn't help. What specifics would you like? Be more specific so I can be also more specific :-) Thank you.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno , this is what I am using too. But when the hash character does not behave as single quotes , double quotes or parenthesis work :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the easiest way to solve this issue, once and for all, was to create my own key binding, like this:

```
{ "keys": ["#"], "command": "insert_snippet","args": {"contents": "#${0:$SELECTION}#"} }
```

This works like a charm!

Comment: I've run into a number of conflicts with mac programs overriding other program's key controls. You might submit this as a basic key control for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably create your own wrapper. Shift + 3 will wrap a string with hash marks.

Comment: Shift+3 won't work :-( Any idea how I could customize this instead? 

Basically what I need, is the same behavior as single quotes , double quotes and parenthesis.